# Why is my AutoCompleteTextView suggestion list getting hidden behind keyboard?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-keypad

I am not able to find a perfect solution for this issue.
I want the keyboard to hide when the user starts scrolling the suggestion list.

I tried this, but it doesn't help

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list_of_Cities) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
                        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity
                                    .getSystemService(
                                            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                                    view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                });
                return v;

            }
        };
```

The onTouch method gets executed, but the keyboard doesn't hide. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try `onItemClickListener`

```
  v.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(arg1.getWindowToken(), 0);

      }

    });
```

Comment: but this will work only when I select one of the items.
I want it to hide when I start scrolling down the list